# C# - use fields and methods without repeating the object name each time

Tags: c#

I've just started learning C#. A common issue I have is when I am working with an object instance and want to access/assign multiple fields then I have to call the object name each time. I come from a background in Delphi and I was wondering if C# has something similar to `with..do` block.

For example. Let's say I had `School` Class with fields `Name` and `Address`

In Delphi, I could do the following

```
mySchool = School.new();
with mySchool do
begin
 Name := 'School Name';
 Address := 'School Address';
end
```

The compiler would understand that `Name` and `Address` are being called on the `mySchool` object.

Whereas in C# I have to do the following

```
mySchool = new School();
mySchool.Name = "School Name";
mySchool.Address = "School Address";
```

I was just wondering if there is a language construct similar to the Delphi one above that would eliminate the need for me to type out the object name repeatedly.

I know in this example is rather trivial and I should rather use a parameterized constructor but my question is for times when I am doing a multitude of things with the same object and having such a language construct would save me quite a bit of typing.

Also, I'm vaguely aware of namespacing although, my understanding is that you can't use an object/variable as a namespace. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You create the class, on the constructor you specify may the passed arguments on the brackets be instantiated as attrs. 

I'm not super savy on c# since i hate microsoft and i only use C# for unity, but since its quite similar to python/java etc it shall be something similar to this

    class School(Name, Address){
    #unsure if you require to call a constructor method or this is sufficient**
    str Name = this.Name;
    str Address = this.Address;
    return School #you may not need to return the class object

mySchool = new School("Hogwarts", "Somewhere Lane")

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) in this case:

```
var mySchool = new School
{
    Name = "School Name",
    Address = "School Address"
};
```

Comment: This is helpful, although what about if I wanted to simply use the object multiple times consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the selected answer doesn't give you what you asked for.

By using object initializer, you will still have to manually type properties' names every time.

A constructor is what you're looking for:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        School school1 = new School("School Name", "School Address");
    }
}

public class School
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public School(string name, string address)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```